# What is the response "." requests?

Tags: dns

I want to ask this question:

What is the "." determination of response status to requests of DNS server?

I dont understand what is the meaning of "." requests.

Can anybody explain it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The zone usually written as a single period character is the root zone. If you sent a query and got information about the root back in the "Additional" part of the response, that means that the name server you sent the question to doesn't know anything about the name you asked about (it also means that the name server is old and should be upgraded, but that's another thing entirely).

If your question was about something else, then I don't understand your question.